# How to use Visual Studio without signing in?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Today, when I open Visual Studio Community 2017, it says the trial period is expired and I must sign in to continue to use. I do not want to create an account although it is free. Can I continue to use it without login?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Login is required per [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/signing-in-to-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) after the trial period. VS Community is free (if you meet the license terms), but you do need to login to renew the license.

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/mlt031819/

If you just want to use the Visual C++ compiler from the command-line, then look at the *Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019* release.

Comment: Is there a way to bypass the login process such as editing the registry? Really not willing to register an account.

Comment: Occasional login to renew the license is how it works. See [this answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/135843/how-to-renew-license-for-visual-studio-community-2.html). Build Tools edition doesn't require a sign-in to my knowledge, but it doesn't provide an IDE either. There's also [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).